# Foundation insert progress bar into top-bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, zurb-foundation

I use the framework Foundation 5, i use the [top bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) and i want to insert into the top-bar a simple [progress bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/progress_bars.html)

The only problem is the progross bar is not horizontal but vertically. It's really strange, i don't know how to correct that.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSu4c/99/)**

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
  <!-- Title -->
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">Sexy Top Bar</a></h1></li>

    <!-- Mobile Menu Toggle -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Top Bar Section -->

<section class="top-bar-section">


    <!-- Top Bar Right Nav Elements -->
    <ul class="right">

       <!-- progess bar bug -->
       <li>
           <div class="progress">
              <span class="meter"></span>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>

      <!-- Anchor -->
      <li><a href="#">Generic Button</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>

      <!-- Button -->
      <li class="has-form show-for-large-up">
        <a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs" class="button">Get Lucky</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section></nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not vertical, it's just doesn't have width.

fix:

```
div.progress{
    width: 500px;
}
```